# Infinite Series: Convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I just came across the following question from an old book:
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\sqrt{k} \pi)}{\sqrt{k}}.$$
Is it convergent? My guess is that it is but how to show it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't look convergent to me. Look at the partial sums: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+cos%28sqrt%28k%29+pi%29%2Fsqrt%28k%29%2C+k%3D1..n

Comment: I see what you mean. But this was up to 1281 terms. It seems to be oscillating but does the amplitude decrease as you move further away? Frequency seems to be decreasing too. Anyhow, I don't think you can tell considering a finite number of terms. We need an argument. If you think it doesn't converge can you give me a proof?

Comment: Do you know cauchy criterion for series ? If so use this to show that the series diverges (by using the first step in integral test).

Comment: @Julien How would you apply the cauchy criterion to show that this diverges?

Comment: @Georgy It actually diverges but the solution is very close to a prize problem:
https://www.facebook.com/294099329615/photos/a.10150101757969616.297491.294099329615/10152768421044616/?type=1&theater
Therefore i cannot post it publicly yet, i will be able to post it in 3-4 days. If you are in a hurry, feel free to contact me on facebook :)

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski Use positiveness of $x\rightarrow \cos(\sqrt{x}\pi)$ on a good interval..

Comment: @Julien Considering that $x$ is an integer in our case, what would a good interval be? :S

Comment: If it converges I think the convergence will come not so much from the growing of the denominator but more because the numerators sort of cancel out if you consider the sums over intervals where the $cos$ changes sign, but that's too vague so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prove the following transformation:
   $\int_{n}^{n+1}f(t)dt=f(n)+\int_{n}^{n+1}([t]+1-t)f'(t)dt$
2. Show that $A_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(n)-\int_{1}^{n+1}f(t)dt$ coverges.
3. Check the convergence of $\int_{1}^{n+1}f(t)dt$. Give a conclusion.

I hope i haven't made any silly mistakes :s

Comment: Nice way of thinking but the integral diverges. It's something like $-2 \sin (\pi \sqrt{n+1})$

Comment: @Georgy Exactly. Therefore the series diverge too. If  $A_n=S_n+I_n$ converges and $I_n$ diverges $=>$ $S_n$ diverges too.

Or are you maybe referring to the problematic part of $ \int_{1}^{n+1} ([t]+1-t)f'(t)dt$ which is $ c\int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{([t]+1-t) \sin(\sqrt{t} \pi)}{t} dt$ ?